# Replacing property of a typescript type

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
type first = {
    one: number;
    two: string;
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number,
    }
}
```

It is applicable to one instance of a variable that I declare in one part of my application, but not exactly applicable to another (second) instance of a variable.

The type that would be suitable for second instance of a variable would look like this:

```
type second = {
    one: number;
    two: string;
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number[], //difference
    }
}
```

I don't want to declare a new type from scratch for a small difference and would like to assimilate the existing type `first` by replacing the type of property `three`.

I tried to do it this way:

```
type second = Pick<first, Exclude<keyof first, 'three'>> & { 
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number[], //difference
    } 
}
```

But it gives me an error and I get this type definition on hover:

```
type second = {
    one: number;
    two: string;
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number,
    };
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number,
    };
}
```

Notice 2 properties `three`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't really reproduce the issue : http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20first%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09one%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09two%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09three%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09four%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09%09five%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20second%20%3D%20Pick%3Cfirst%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20first%2C%20'three'%3E%3E%20%26%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09three%3A%20%7B%20four%3A%20string%2C%20five%3A%20number%5B%5D%2C%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20d%3A%20second%20%3D%20%7Bone%3A%201%2Ctwo%3A%20%22%22%2Cthree%20%3A%20%7Bfour%3A%20%22%22%2Cfive%3A%20%5B0%5D%7D%7D

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I think I got confused by the schema of the type "second" displayed by Typescript, which did not resolve the "Pick" part leaving its definition instead of the result of its application (I had the text "Pick<>" in the schema).

Comment: Yeah ... exactly what is expanded in the types is still a mystery for me personally...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You solution should work, I just have two observations:

1. You can use the same approach one level down using type queries, no need to rewrite the inner object
2. Careful with intersection types, the assumption that they behave exactly the same as hand crafted type is not always true. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324284/typescript-intersection-type-and-function-signature-not-throwing-expected-error/51330053#51330053). We can get around such issues flattening the type using an additional mapped type.

With these in mind this is what I would do:

```
type first = {
    one: number;
    two: string;
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number,
    }
}

type Identity<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
type Replace<T, K extends keyof T, TReplace> = Identity<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & {
    [P in K] : TReplace
}>

type second = Replace<first, 'three', Replace<first['three'], 'five', number[]>>
let d: second = {
    one: 1,
    two: "",
    three : {
        four: "",
        five: [0]
    }
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20first%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20one%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20two%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20three%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20four%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20five%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Identity%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Replace%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20TReplace%3E%20%3D%20Identity%3CPick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%20%3A%20TReplace%0D%0A%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20second%20%3D%20Replace%3Cfirst%2C%20'three'%2C%20Replace%3Cfirst%5B'three'%5D%2C%20'five'%2C%20number%5B%5D%3E%3E%0D%0Alet%20d%3A%20second%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20one%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20two%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20three%20%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20four%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20five%3A%20%5B0%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: Why did you call "Flatten" type this way? We do not flatten the object here, do we? Flattening is making an object one level shallower as far as I understand. But it seems that in your example we kind of duplicate the object by remapping?

Comment: @Eduard flatten was the wrong name perhaps .. it's flattening out the intersection types ...I changed the name to `Identity`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Now I understand. Really appreciate your answers!

Comment: It was a real pain to read mapped types before. Thanks for this "Identity" trick! I am going to use it everywhere now 

Comment: This solution is grand, but seems to came up before `Omit<Type, Keys>` was born. (TS 3.5). It appears to me that this should do: `type Replace<T, K extends keyof T, TReplace> = Omit<T, K> & { [P in K]: TReplace }`

Answer (score 10):

You could just try to replace a part of the type definition, by using a union. The following is an oversimplification:

```
type SecondType = FirstType & {
   three: {
        four: string,
        five: number[],
    }
  };
```

The solution mentioned above will get you in trouble. A simple union doesn't really replace property "three", it actually creates 2 conflicting definitions for properties "three" and "five". Your IDE will give you warnings whenever you try to access them.

**A solution, is to remove the property and then merge it back in:**

```
type SecondType = 
   Omit<FirstType, 'three'> & 
   { three: {
        four: string,
        five: number[]
   }};
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Titian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599774/6219628).

If stacking multiple `Override`s becomes too confusing/impractical, you may use this tweaked version:

```
/**
 * Merge keys of U into T, overriding value types with those in U.
 */
type Override<T, U extends Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>> = FinalType<Omit<T, keyof U> & U>
```

`FinalType` is a type utility that improves the readability of the final resulting type prodived by your lsp (as shown in your editor).
Instead of seeing a bunch of utility types wrapping your initial type,
you get the final type as if you had written it yourself.

Here is a definition (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683575/6219628)):

```
/**
 * Make a type assembled from several types/utilities more readable.
 * (e.g. the type will be shown as the final resulting type instead of as a bunch of type utils wrapping the initial type).
 */
type FinalType<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never
```

So, reusing the original question's example:

```
type InitialType = {
    one: number;
    two: string;
    three: {
        four: string,
        five: number,
    }
}
```

You may use `Override` this way:

```
type Transformed = Override<InitialType, {
    three: {
        four: string
        five: number[]
    }
}>
```

I tested all this in [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBASQHYEswoIYBsAq14C8cA3qHOXAPZIwBccSArgLYBGMATgNxkVgDulegGcwHFEgDmPEBThgAFhxh0SvOeQBmlRhxFiJkgDTqNmlADdVTNpxOyKAX1DOQoSLDgAxCdjywAHhwAPjgiHDgYAA8wGCQAE2E4CU1OOABVOAB+EjgAbQBpZKQ4AGsYCEpNDIBdenTCmrhHOHoaKw5Qd3w4AHkO8XiYIKMMyJi4xLgABQwOdGwAgCUYAGNKDniA8srqnFHGJFKkSn4kYIuw719cfADplFXSkbgAUSjVrEYh7YqquH2ZT+1XSlwAZBlgl1wD1+pxBjAAEwvTLRWIJJKzeaYLDLNYbLY7f6Aw7HU7nS5EHxIPx3XrMNAvIkg0IQ0HQjzwHAcDBIYTaDjMGDxK5wjgIgLINA4-wwUakBzkRTKVQKjQUbS6fTiKSmOTmKxtFjsDh5GqmVyOKFuGGebm8-kbIXxRGigYoIbIqULW6weWmZUqehq9VwTV6OCiHWSPUayzWY2cM0WlzW0DrPlgYrS7D0b0ynpEEPUVQAFkR9iVgnoACJywAGGuV+RKINqRVhnQRuuI+uN5taeP0Bt95uW6EZ0TyHl8gXO+j22dO4VXYs0YcV3gCIRwHv9ret1WmcO1kdN49D-Ij+s1McuCfUKdiB1z4WIhczx2Ct+r3gljfNtup69ueDiBkeHYnruZ4DmGl55Net68OOIBAA)

Comment: `type Override` works but without `ReadableType` type. Also it is not defined in answer.

Comment: I suggest the following improved version of Override: 

`type Override<T, U extends Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U;`

this replaces the Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof O>>, which I think just picks all attributes of T that are not in O, with Omit all attributes that are in O. This is a little bit shorter and does the same thing in the end I think.

Also uses unknown instead of any.

Comment: @AlexPo thanks, it seems I failed to double check after a last minute rename. Fixed that and renamed everything to FinalType, plus changed the docstring.

Comment: @Marnix neat suggestion. I changed the definition in the rewritten answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the same method previously by doing an `Omit` first and then merging with `&`, so I made a utility type `Replace`:

```
type Replace<
  TypeToBeChecked,
  KeyToBeReplaced extends keyof TypeToBeChecked,
  NewValueToUse
> = Omit<TypeToBeChecked, KeyToBeReplaced> & {
  [P in KeyToBeReplaced]: NewValueToUse
}
```

We can use it like this:

```
type NewType = Replace<OldType, KeyInOldType, NewValueForTheSameKey>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an override(deep) version:

```
type Override<T, TypeToReplace, TypeToReplaceWith> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ? Override<T[K], TypeToReplace, TypeToReplaceWith> : T[K] extends TypeToReplace ? TypeToReplaceWith : T[K]
}
```